# Find last HTML element in the same row in a text

Tags: javascript

I have HTML code like this:

```
<span> h</span>
<span> e</span>
<span> l</span>
<span> l</span>
<span> o</span>
<span> <br/></span>
<span> w</span>
<span> o</span>
<span> r</span>
<span> l</span>
<span> d</span>
<span> <br/></span>
<span> !</span>
```

What I want is when user click, for example, the 'e' in "hello", I need to find the last character in the row and the first character in the next row, so the result I want is 'o' in "hello" and 'w' in "world" need to be returned.

Comment: Is redesigning this craptacular HTML an option?

Comment: @Paul the reason why each character is in a span is because each character has it's own mouseup and down handler in the real code, I ignored it.

Comment: Right, but if you grouped each line into a block element (e.g. div) rather than using breaks (<br>), this problem gets much, much easier.

Comment: For that matter, the parent element could hold the event handlers, and you could figure out which actual span was clicked via event target.

Comment: @Paul thanks for your comment, it's not easy to make that change because of the complicated logic. What should I do if I don't change the HTML structure?

Comment: If you include your complicated logic here we might be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new on here - but will give it a go :)

Admittedly not the most elegant solution.. but you maybe able to tweak depending on your code structure / needs.

I'm assuming that all spans are wrapped in a parent node?

If you are attaching the click event to the parent node, this snippet could do the trick...

```js
// callback handler
function handleClick(e) {
  // target is the actual element clicked
  var selected = e.target;
  // you may need to run some element checks, for now just making sure is a span
  if (selected.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'span') {
    // ignore it, some dead space got clicked
    return;
  }
  // grab the inner text of the selected element
  var selectedText = selected.innerText;
  // get all the elements in the same container
  var elements = selected.parentNode.childNodes;
  // store found results
  var results = [];
  // loop elements
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements[i] === selected) {
      // if element matches, push to results
      results.push(elements[i]);
    } else {
      // otherwise get element text
      var elementText = elements[i].innerText;
      // make sure we have element text due to the <br/> tags :)
      if (elementText) {
        // compare last letter ( i think this is what you wanted? otherwise just match the whole innerText )
        if (elementText.substr(elementText.length - 1) === selectedText.substr(selectedText.length - 1)) {
          // if match, add to results
          results.push(elements[i]);
        }
      }

    }

  }

  // do what is needed with the results
  console.log(results);
}

document.getElementById('parentNode').addEventListener('click', handleClick);
```

```html
<div id="parentNode">
  <span> h</span>
  <span> e</span>
  <span> l</span>
  <span> l</span>
  <span> o</span>
  <span> <br/></span>
  <span> w</span>
  <span> o</span>
  <span> r</span>
  <span> l</span>
  <span> d</span>
  <span> <br/></span>
  <span> !</span>
</div>
```

Otherwise if you're attaching the click event to each span, then is just a couple of minor tweaks

- Use currentTarget to get selected element ( currentTarget returns element with event, target returns element clicked )
- No need to run the element check as you know what has been clicked

```js
// callback handler
function handleClick(e) {
  // grab selected element
  var selected = e.currentTarget;
  // grab the inner text of the selected element
  var selectedText = selected.innerText;
  // get all the elements in the same container
  var elements = selected.parentNode.childNodes;
  // store found results
  var results = [];
  // loop elements
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements[i] === selected) {
      // if element matches, push to results
      results.push(elements[i]);
    } else {
      // otherwise get element text
      var elementText = elements[i].innerText;
      // make sure we have element text due to the <br/> tags :)
      if (elementText) {
        // compare last letter ( i think this is what you wanted? otherwise just match the whole innerText )
        if (elementText.substr(elementText.length - 1) === selectedText.substr(selectedText.length - 1)) {
          // if match, add to results
          results.push(elements[i]);
        }
      }

    }

  }

  // do what is needed with the results
  console.log(results);
}

// attach click events
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  spans[i].addEventListener('click', handleClick);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span> h</span>
  <span> e</span>
  <span> l</span>
  <span> l</span>
  <span> o</span>
  <span> <br/></span>
  <span> w</span>
  <span> o</span>
  <span> r</span>
  <span> l</span>
  <span> d</span>
  <span> <br/></span>
  <span> !</span>
</div>
```

Hope this helps in some way :)